# Cannot overwrite `categories` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, mongoose

** Cannot overwrite `categories` model once compiled. **

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create url connect data base
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/STOREBOOKS";

// create  category for schema
const category = schema({
  name: String,
});

// create crcategory in model categores
const Cats = mongoose.model("categoreis", category);

// this function return all categories of Promise
exports.getAllcategories = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose
      .connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      })
      .then(() => Cats.find())
      .then((cats) => {
        mongoose.disconnect();
        resolve(cats);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

```
** throw new _mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name);**
```

Comment: is `categoreis` in the code `const Cats = mongoose.model("categoreis", category);` a typo?

Comment: also, no need to create a new Promise that "wraps" a Promise chain

Comment: I fixed the error, and the problem remains